# Read a file word by word with read()

Tags: c, file, io, posix

I'm doing a program that reads a file in the command line argument, and creates a new file for every word it reads.

Ex. 1 file with 10 word becomes ----> 10 files with one word in each.

I've got it to work using fread,fwrite,fget, etc ... , but we are only allowed to use read() and write() to read/write from the file. Doing it this way seem ridiculously hard at the moment as well as unnecessary,I am starting to think our teacher just told us wrong, so my three questions are:

1. Is this possible to do?
2. Is it done by manipulating the bytes read() takes in?
3. Can someone explain in layman's term how to manipulate read()/write() to take in various words of different lengths

I understand read() reads from an input stream and then puts it into a buffer but I'm pretty sure isn't like Java where I can give it a start and stop position and it will read everything in between, then continue reading from position stop+1.

Comment: (1) Yes! If you can do it with `fread()` and `fwrite()` (and `fopen()` and `fclose()`), then you can do it with the file descriptor I/O functions.  There's a direct mapping for each of the functions — assuming the file is a disk file, not a non-seekable device like a terminal or pipe or FIFO, and that you never tried to `ungetc()` a character that you hadn't just read. (2) It would be easier to see your code, but you could easily write little functions to do the same job as the standard I/O functions.  (3) Like `fread()` and `fwrite()`, but you give a simply byte count.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph: How did you manage this with `fread` etc?

Comment: If you got it to work with `fread`, you already have it working with `read`, provided you handle any of the usual buffering provided by the `stdio` library yourself. The behavior is different (e.g. you might read/write fewer bytes than you intended on occasion), but the idea is the same: read bytes, write the words found in the bytes read to separate files, accounting for the case of partial words read.

Answer (score 1):

Is not that complicated, here is a snippet that shows how to read contents from a file:

```
int fd = open("input.txt", O_RDONLY); // fd stands for file descriptor
int length, i;
char buffer[1000];
length = read(fd, buffer, 1000); // read() return the number of read characters
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    putchar(buffer[i]);
}
printf("\n");
close(fd);
```

For more information about `open()`, `read()` and `close()` see use `man 2 function`. In the man pages are listed the header files you need to compile the code.

The writing will look like this:

```
fd = open("output.txt", O_WRONLY);
write(fd, word, strlen(word)); // word is an array of char.
```

Comment: I would `read` larger buffers (e.g. of 8Kbytes = 8192 bytes), and I would perhaps make the buffer `static`

Comment: Well, this is just an example. The size of the buffer depends much on the input size and other factors.

Comment: Tell me if I am reading this correctly. Your read() reads everything in the file and returns how long the file. Also read() is storing the whole file in buffer[] of char type(or are you storing it when you run the for-loop). Finally does the buffer[] store "spaces", would I have to do some type of loop to check for "spaces" and extract every word out of buffer[] before writing it?

Comment: The line `length = read(fd, buffer, 1000);` read 1000 characters from the file, if there are more characters in you file just increase this number. The `for` loop is not necessary, it is there just to show what was read from the file.

Comment: From "I've got it to work using fread,fwrite,fget, etc" I understand that you already know how to solve the problem (extract the words), you're just having problems with the I/O. Yes, `buffer[]` has letters and spaces (if they are present in the file).

Answer (score 0):

The [`read()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html) call works something like this:

```
int read( int handle, void *buffer, int nbyte );
```

where: `handle` is the file descriptor, `buffer` is where the bytes read are stored, `nbyte` is the number of bytes to be read.

To do what you have been told to do, I think you will have to iterate on the file descriptor to first see how long the word is, then `lseek()` back to the starting point of the (easy, as you now know the length of the word) and then read it using `read()`.

Comment: "iterate on the file pointer to first see whow long the word" - what file pointer?

Comment: No need to `lseek`, just use wide buffering.

Comment: I am a bit confused with "iterate on the file pointer", is there a specific function that does this. Also after doing lseek() and read() would i have to use lseek() to go to the beginning of the next work in the file, find its length, and read it?

Comment: @BrettJami: How do you handle finding the words in your code with `fread()` etc?  You do it the same basic way with `read()` etc.  The main difference is that the standard I/O functions have buffers to store extra data when the low-level reads are performed (since the standard I/O functions use the low-level reads themselves).  Maybe you should show us the `fread()`-based code you claim to have working, and then you can explain where you're having problems with the translation/conversion.